# Way to create a tree from two lists with a matching ID

Tags: c#

Let`s say I have the following two models :

```
public class Order
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public IList<Appointment> Appointments { get; set; }
}

public class Appointment
{
    public Guid Id {get; set;}
    public DateTime StartDate {get; set;}
    public DateTime EndDate {get; set;}
    public Guid OrderId { get; set; }

}
```

I have a list with Order items (all with the list of Appointments empty) and a list with all appointments and I don`t know how to match elements from the two lists in order to obtain the Order object with all corresponding appointments (based on OrderId).

How can I do that in an efficient manner ? I don`t want to iterate through all orders, and assign the corresponding appointments..

Comment: What have you tried so far? What didn't work? What method do you have that populates `Appointment`? Are you using EF, ADO, etc? It's pretty easy once we see what you have tried or what you're using to populate your entities.

Comment: Shouldn't the `Appointments` property on any instance of the `Order` object be populated with the corresponding `Appointment` objects from the data store?  It's not really clear what the problem is.  Where are you getting your instances of these classes and how are they being populated with data?

Comment: I`m working with Nhibernate criteria, the example is much more complex, but after 2 joins and after the mapping on 2 DTOs OrderDto and AppointmentsDto, I have to merge them somehow, efficiently

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to "group join" the two lists and project a new collection:

```
var neworders = 
    from o in orders
    join a in appointments
      on o.Id equals a.OrderId 
      into g
    select new Order
    {
       Id = o.Id,
       Name = o.Name,
       Location = o.Location,
       Street = o.Street,
       Appointments = g.ToList()
    };
```

Obviously this creates *new* `Order` objects - if that is not desirable another option would be to loop through all of the orders and "attach" the matching appointments - using `ToLookup` to pre-group them:

```
var groups = appointments.ToLookup(a => a.OrderId);

foreach(var o in orders)
    o.Appointments = groups[o.Id].ToList();
```

Comment: That is what I`m looking for! Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

First, make a dictionary of `Appointment` by `OrderId`:

```
var appointmentByOrderId = appointments
    .GroupBy(a => a.OrderId)
    .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.ToList());
```

After that walk through the list of `Order`s, and set `Appointments` to the list from the dictionary:

```
foreach (var order in orders) {
    List<Appointment> appointmentList;
    if (appointmentByOrderId.TryGetValue(order.Id, out appointmentList) {
        order.Appointments = appointmentList;
    } else {
        order.Appointments = new List<Appointment>();
    }
}
```

The `else` branch is optional. You can drop it if you do not want to set an empty list to orders with empty appointment lists.

Answer (score 1):

Build a `Dictionary<Guid, Order>`, and populate it with all of your orders. Then go through the list of appointments and add to the proper order. For example (assuming you have a list called `Orders` and a list called `Appointments`):

```
var OrdersDictionary = Orders.ToDictionary(o => o.Id, o => o);

foreach (var appt in Appointments)
{
    OrdersDictionary[appt.OrderId].Appointments.Add(appt);
}
```

There's probably a LINQ way to do that rollup all in a single statement, but I didn't take the time to puzzle it out.